# changing element ID to data-code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

instead of using the `ID element`, `data-code`. Do I just change everything that is `.getElementById` to `getElementByData-code` ?

```
// form validation function //
function validate(form) {
  var s_name = form.s_name.value;
  var s_email = form.s_email.value;
  var s_drop = form.s_drop.value;
// var s_promo = form.s_promo.value;
  var nameRegex = /^[A-Za-z\d_]+$/;
  var emailRegex = /^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$/;
  var msgRegex = new RegExp(/<\/?\w+((\s+\w+(\s*=\s*(?:".*?"|'.*?'|[^'">\s]+))?)+\s*|\s*)\/?>/gim);
  if(s_name == "") {
    inlineMsg('s_name','You must enter your name.',2);
    return false;
  }
  if(!s_name.match(nameRegex)) {
    inlineMsg('s_txt','You have entered an invalid name.',2);
    return false;
  }
  if(s_email == "") {
    inlineMsg('s_email','<strong>Error</strong><br />You must enter your email.',2);
    return false;
  }
  if(!s_email.match(emailRegex)) {
    inlineMsg('s_email','<strong>Error</strong><br />You have entered an invalid email.',2);
    return false;
  }
  if(s_drop == "") {
    inlineMsg('s_drop','<strong>Error</strong><br />You must select your gender.',2);
    return false;
  }
/*
  if(s_promo == "") {
    inlineMsg('s_promo','You must enter a message.');
    return false;
  }
*/  
  if(s_promo.match(msgRegex)) {
    inlineMsg('s_promo','You have entered an invalid message.',2);
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

// START OF MESSAGE SCRIPT //

var MSGTIMER = 20;
var MSGSPEED = 5;
var MSGOFFSET = 3;
var MSGHIDE = 3;

// build out the divs, set attributes and call the fade function //
function inlineMsg(target,string,autohide) {
  var msg;
  var msgcontent;
  if(!document.getElementById('msg')) {
    msg = document.createElement('div');
    msg.id = 'msg';
    msgcontent = document.createElement('div');
    msgcontent.id = 'msgcontent';
    document.body.appendChild(msg);
    msg.appendChild(msgcontent);
    msg.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=0)';
    msg.style.opacity = 0;
    msg.alpha = 0;
  } else {
    msg = document.getElementById('msg');
    msgcontent = document.getElementById('msgcontent');
  }
  msgcontent.innerHTML = string;
  msg.style.display = 'block';
  var msgheight = msg.offsetHeight;
  var targetdiv = document.getElementById(target);
  targetdiv.focus();
  var targetheight = targetdiv.offsetHeight;
  var targetwidth = targetdiv.offsetWidth;
  var topposition = topPosition(targetdiv) - ((msgheight - targetheight) / 2);
  var leftposition = leftPosition(targetdiv) + targetwidth + MSGOFFSET;
  msg.style.top = topposition + 'px';
  msg.style.left = leftposition + 'px';
  clearInterval(msg.timer);
  msg.timer = setInterval("fadeMsg(1)", MSGTIMER);
  if(!autohide) {
    autohide = MSGHIDE;  
  }
  window.setTimeout("hideMsg()", (autohide * 1000));
}

// hide the form alert //
function hideMsg(msg) {
  var msg = document.getElementById('msg');
  if(!msg.timer) {
    msg.timer = setInterval("fadeMsg(0)", MSGTIMER);
  }
}

// face the message box //
function fadeMsg(flag) {
  if(flag == null) {
    flag = 1;
  }
  var msg = document.getElementById('msg');
  var value;
  if(flag == 1) {
    value = msg.alpha + MSGSPEED;
  } else {
    value = msg.alpha - MSGSPEED;
  }
  msg.alpha = value;
  msg.style.opacity = (value / 100);
  msg.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + value + ')';
  if(value >= 99) {
    clearInterval(msg.timer);
    msg.timer = null;
  } else if(value <= 1) {
    msg.style.display = "none";
    clearInterval(msg.timer);
  }
}
```

Comment: Show us your HTML so we can see what Javascript would make sense for finding the desired elements.  There is no function `document.getElementByData-code()` so you cannot use that.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery, you can use the Sizzle Selection Engine (packaged with jQuery) to select the elements you want by attribute:

```
//this will select all elements with the `data-code` attribute with a value of `whatever`
var data_codes = $('[data-code="whatever"]');
```

You can also just select all elements with a certain attribute regardless of the value of that attribute:

```
var data_codes = $('[data-code]');
```

Here's a list of selector types that jQuery has (at the top of the list are the attribute selectors): http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Note that `document.getElementById('SOME_ID')` is the same as `$('#some_id')[0]`. I added the `[0]` to the end of the jQuery selection to return just the DOM node. You are using other functions that jQuery makes easier as well. `.innerHTML = 'some string';` is the same as `.html('some string');`, `.style.display = 'block'` is the same as `.show()` or `.css({display: 'block'})`.

Comment: `var s_name = $('[data-code]');` is the same as `var s_name = form.s_name.value;` it'll grab the value correct?